# Tab buttons exist but are not visible

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I have a tab component with two tabs. The buttons are clickable, and clicking on where the buttons should be is correctly displaying the tab contents, but the buttons are invisible.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{coupon.title}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div class="coupon-image-container">
    <img src={{coupon.mainImage}}/>
    <button ion-button class="left">Redeem</button>
  </div>
  <ion-tabs class="coupon-tabs">
    <ion-tab tabIcon="map" [root]="mapTab" tabTitle="Map"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabIcon="information" [root]="infoTab" tabTitle="Info"></ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>
</ion-content>
```

I don't think any other code is necessary but I'll provide more if needed. Like I said the contents of the `mapTab` and `infoTab` components are showing up fine, and clicking on where the tab buttons should be is switching between them, but the buttons are just blank white.

Edit: Just in case someone was going to ask, it still does the same thing if I remove everything else in the component except for the tab component like so:

```
<ion-tabs class="coupon-tabs">
  <ion-tab tabIcon="map" [root]="mapTab" tabTitle="Map"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tabIcon="information" [root]="infoTab" tabTitle="Info"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

So it definitely has nothing to do with the other content.

Edit: I made a gif showing the problem: http://g.recordit.co/WDkjkSz6re.gif

Edit: Here's the styles on ion-tab

```
element.style {
}
main.css:25224
.coupon-tabs ion-tab {
    color: black;
    top: 56px;
}
main.css:5136
ion-tab.show-tab {
    display: block;
}
main.css:5145
ion-app, ion-nav, ion-tab, ion-tabs, .app-root, .ion-page {
    contain: strict;
}
main.css:5132
ion-tab {
    display: none;
}
main.css:5128
ion-nav, ion-tab, ion-tabs {
    overflow: hidden;
}
main.css:5116
ion-app, ion-nav, ion-tab, ion-tabs, .app-root {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

main.css:4986
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
Inherited from ion-tabs.coupon-tabs.tabs.tabs-md.tabs-md-primary
main.css:25219
.coupon-tabs {
    position: relative;
    color: black;
}
main.css:4986
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

Comment: maybe the coupon-tabs class?

Comment: @ZhangBruce That doesn't have any properties set on it as of yet.

Comment: that's weird, I have exact same code but a  color="white" attributes in ion-tabs

Comment: Can we have a working plunker?

Comment: @Sampath Well, I tried... https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue I couldn't get it to work at all though. I've never used plunker.

Comment: Yes, Then can you provide the minimal working project on Git? Then we can play with it no?

Comment: In my code I use class="tabs-positive". Not sure where I got that from and where you got "coupon-tabs". But that works fine for me.
I also define the attributes in the sequence [root] tabTitle tabIcon, but I wouldn't have thought that to be critical. Also Is mapTab/infoTab pointing to a lazy load page string or a component?

Comment: " it still does the same thing if I remove everything else in the component except for the tab component" what exactly does it show?

Comment: I remember I have this kind of problem before, Have you tried `inspect element` then select `ion-tab` and post the styles here in your post, also a screenshot of what you are currently seeing. This is just an assumption though I think it has something to do with `[aria-hidden]` attribute that magically appears in your rendered template. this `[aria-hidden]` has a property of hiding an element that contains it.

Comment: @masterpreenz I updated the post with a video of the problem

Comment: @chrispytoes What I was needed was the result of inpect element, the styles that appears on inspect element when you select a `tab`

Answer (score 2):

Look for class .tabbar and check its opacity. Change it if needed.

Answer (score 0):

do this instead:

```
<ion-tab icon="ion-map" title="Map"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab icon="ion-ios-information" title="Info"></ion-tab>
```

after you do this you might have noticed that text do not appear, though the text did appear but it was way below the icon and was hidden by `overflow`. You might need to move the text a bit higher with `position: relative; top: -XXpx` or make parent `overflow: visible`.

If you aren't building the project with `typescript` I guess the issue was `tabTitle` and `tabIcon` was not translated properly to the example above or If you we're building this project with `typescript` then it fails to translate the attributes to its proper way.

hope that helps

[I saw some other issues in google related to this](http://[https://www.google.com.ph/search?q=ion-tab%20title%20icon%20does%20not%20appear&oq=ion-tab%20title%20icon%20does%20not%20appear&aqs=chrome..69i57.4421j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I tried your code and the tab buttons are still blank, but the tab content is not visible anymore as you said. Exactly what elements do I need to change those properties on? Also the tabview is now making itself too tall and causing the screen to scroll, and the tab content area is blank, and just shows an empty div in inspect element. I am using Typescript.

Comment: based on [tab.ts in Ionic2 source](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/tabs/tab.ts) `tabTitle` and `tabIcon` should be correct as have type string. have you tried `tabTitle="'Info'" tabIcon="'ion-ios-information'"`? with the quotes as previously it was looking for a variable named `Info` with quotes you are just sending it a data directly.

Comment: Just tried adding the quotes there, and nothing changed. And they probably should have been there anyway because those are not variables.

Comment: I could not guess anymore what is going on unless I see the source `inspect element thingy` to find out what's going on in the DOM. I think it is much better creating your own `tabs` simply just replicating the layout of `ion-tab`. What's going on was the component `ion-tab` fails to recognize the `@Input attribute tabIcon / tabTitle` or it fails to recognize the values of those `@Input attributes` or there is something wrong with the `@Component <ion-tab>` at all.

Comment: I am trying to replicate the issue with the typescript version, hopefully will find the cause

Comment: there was no problems at all with this version `"ionic-angular": "3.6.0"`, [ionic2 typescript starter I used](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-starter-tabs)

Answer (score 0):

Mine was because i initialised the tabs properties in the top of the class instead of the constructor

This one below doesn't work.

```
export class TabsPage {
    tab1 = Page1;
    tab2 = Page2;

    constructor() {}
}
```

This one worked fine.

```
export class TabsPage {

  tab1: any;
  tab2: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.tab1 = Page1;
    this.tab2 = Page2;
  }

}
```

Also, for some reason tabs were not showing up on the screen, although they were present in the DOM, maybe because i had nested tabs in my app. So had to add this in the tabs-page.scss

```
.tabbar {
    opacity: 1;
}
```